# Python3.10 sqlite3 - multithreading writes lost data

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

When I try to batch insert data into sqlite using multithreading, it randomly loses data. The problem can be reproduced with the following code.

```py
import sqlite3
import contextlib
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


@contextlib.contextmanager
def append_exit(contextmanager, func):
    try:
        with contextmanager:
            yield
    finally:
        func()


e = ThreadPoolExecutor()

c = sqlite3.connect("t")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")


def write():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("t", isolation_level=None)
    with append_exit(connection, connection.close):
        connection.execute("BEGIN")
        parameters = [["a"] for i in range(100)]
        connection.executemany("INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES (?)", parameters)


for i in range(1000):
    e.submit(write)

e.shutdown(wait=True)

print(c.execute("SELECT * FROM t").fetchall())
```

How to solve the problem of data loss?

Comment: I don't get it, if I copy/paste your code and check how many rows are created after running it, it's exactly as expected, 100K entries. So where is the data loss?

Comment: @user56700 On my computer it randomly loses around two thousand pieces of data.

Comment: I tried your code on both my work laptop and personal computer and none of them loses any data.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest not opening the database every time you write to it? Keep the database open while you write to it in a context manager and let it commit and close whenever all data is written. This code takes around a second to execute:

```
import sqlite3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def write(connection):
    parameters = [["a"] for i in range(100)]
    connection.executemany("INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES (?)", parameters)

e = ThreadPoolExecutor()

with sqlite3.connect("t") as c:
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
    for i in range(1000):
        e.submit(write(c))
    e.shutdown(wait=True)
    print(len(c.execute("SELECT * FROM t").fetchall()))
```

Result:

```
100000
```

Sample data:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'a'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'a'), (8, 'a'), (9, 'a'), (10, 'a'), (11, 'a'), (12, 'a'), (13, 'a'), (14, 'a'), (15, 'a'), (16, 'a'), (17, 'a'), (18, 'a'), (19, 'a'), (20, 'a'), (21, 'a'), (22, 'a'), (23, 'a'), (24, 'a'), (25, 'a'), (26, 'a'), (27, 'a'), (28, 'a'), (29, 'a'), (30, 'a'), (31, 'a'), (32, 'a'), (33, 'a'), (34, 'a'), (35, 'a'), (36, 'a'), (37, 'a'), (38, 
'a'), (39, 'a'), (40, 'a'), (41, 'a'), (42, 'a'), (43, 'a'), (44, 'a'), (45, 'a'), (46, 'a'), (47, 'a'), (48, 'a'), (49, 'a'), (50, 'a'), (51, 'a'), (52, 'a'), (53, 'a'), (54, 'a'), (55, 'a'), (56, 'a'), (57, 'a'), (58, 'a'), (59, 'a'), (60, 'a'), (61, 'a'), (62, 'a'), (63, 'a'), (64, 'a'), (65, 'a'), (66, 'a'), (67, 'a'), (68, 'a'), (69, 'a'), (70, 'a'), (71, 'a'), (72, 'a'), (73, 'a'), (74, 'a'), (75, 'a'), (76, 'a'), (77, 'a'), (78, 'a'), (79, 'a'), (80, 'a'), (81, 'a'), (82, 'a'), (83, 'a'), (84, 'a'), (85, 'a'), (86, 'a'), (87, 'a'), (88, 'a'), (89, 'a'), (90, 'a'), (91, 'a'), (92, 'a'), (93, 'a'), (94, 'a'), (95, 'a'), (96, 'a'), (97, 'a'), (98, 'a'), (99, 'a'), (100, 'a'), (101, 'a'), (102, 'a'), (103, 'a'), (104, 'a'), (105, 'a'), (106, 'a'), (107, 'a'), (108, 'a'), (109, 'a'), (110, 'a'), (111, 'a'), (112, 'a'), (113, 'a'), (114, 'a'), (115, 'a'), (116, 'a'), (117, 'a'), (118, 'a'), (119, 'a'), (120, 'a'), (121, 'a'), (122, 'a'), (123, 'a'), (124, 'a'), (125, 'a'), (126, 'a'), (127, 'a'), (128, 'a'), (129, 'a'), (130, 'a'), (131, 'a'), (132, 'a'), (133, 'a'), (134, 'a'), (135, 'a')...
```

Comment: This is the simplified code... I can't keep the connection in the actual project code